# When using parent to child SOQL query, why don't we denote the variable receiving the query as a list?

Tags: apex, soql

I've noticed that when using parent to child SOQL query we mark the receiving variables as if they will receive a single record but these variables will in fact receive a list of record.

as you could see below:

```
for(Account MyAccountList : [select id, (select id from contacts) from account where id in :accountIds])
    {
        for(Contact MyContactList : MyAccountList.contacts)
        {            
          ......            
        }
    }
```

Is there a reason I don't understand for doing this?

Comment: No it is not the case always. There is no mandate on receiving end, you can have single object or can have list as well.

Comment: If you look at the syntax of the for loop it receives a list as a parameter and iterates through them one by one, so the `MyAccountList`  is an inappropriate variable name here, it should be `myAccount`. The child relationship query always return a list. It would be nice if you could reframe your question and make more clear.

Comment: yes, it makes sense thanks @rahulgawale

Answer (score 0):

It's Because there may be a chance in the future when there will be more than one record. In that case if your logic running for a single record then your functionality fails. Due to that salesforce always return list so that if there is more than single record it will not fail.